# proving that the sum of areas of two opposite triangles within a parallelogram is equal to the sum of the other two

Tags: geometry

I was told that no matter which dot on a parallelogram you would choose, if you connect all four corners to that dot, the sum of the two opposite triangles will be equal to the sum of the other two.

In the following picture that would mean that the sum of triangles APB and DPC will be equal to the sum of triangles APD and BPC: [image]

While I believe it's true, I want to be sure, so I am trying to come up with a way of how to prove it. How can I do that?

Comment: Hint: the sum of the heights against the parallelogram sides of two opposite triangles is $\dots$

Comment: @dxiv - ...is equal to the sum of the other two triangles' heights. But what will it give me?

Comment: @dxiv - Besides, that "the sum of the heights against the parallelogram sides of two opposite triangles is equal to the sum of the other two triangles' heights" still needs to proven somehow first.

Comment: No, those sums are not equal. If you look at your drawing, do $AB,CD$ and $AD,BC$ appear to be at the same distance?

Comment: @dxiv - No. AB looks farther away from CD than AD from BC.

Comment: @dxiv - Then I am completely unaware of what you were hinting at.

Comment: Construct a line through $P$ that is perpendicular to $\overline {AB}$ and $\overline {CD}.$  Lets call this line $\overline {EF}.$  $P$ breaks $\overline {EF}$ into two pieces of length $h_1$ and $h_2.$  The area of the two triangles is $A =\frac 12  AB\cdot h_1 + \frac 12 CD\cdot h_2$ but since $AB = CD$ we can say $A = \frac12 AB\cdot (h_1+h_2) = \frac 12 AB\cdot EF$ regardless of where $P$ lies on $\overline{EF}$  and wherever $P$ lies in the box the measure of $EF$ does not change.

Comment: @brilliant The sum of the heights of two opposite triangles is the distance between the respective parallel sides, and does not depend on $P$. Now write down the triangle areas, add them up, and compare to the area of the whole parallelogram.

Comment: @DougM - Thank you, Doug. So, from your post I can see clearly now that EF doesn't change for triangles APB and DPC. And if I do the same for the other two triangles - let's call that line GH - I will know for sure that the measure GH won't be changing either. But still, how does all of that prove that the areas of the sums of pairs of opposite triangles are equal?

Comment: The measure of EF is the height of the parallelogram from the point of view that AB is the base.  Hence the sum of $ABP$ and $CDP$ are half the area of the parallelogram.  Similarly the areas of $ADP$ and $BCP$ sum to half the area of the parallelogram.

Comment: @DougM - Ah! I see now. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call $AD=BC=b$, the "base" length, and the perpendicular height $h$  (the shortest distance between lines $AD$ and $BC$).

The area of a parallelogram is its perpendicular height $h$ multiplied by the base $b$ (the length $AD$ or $BC$). You can see this by cutting the end off the parallelogram and joining it to make a rectangle of dimensions $h\times b$ with the same area as the parallelogram.

The area of a triangle is half the perpendicular distance from the base to the apex $P$, multiplied by the base, which is $b$ for $AD$ or $BC$.

So the area $A$ of triangles $\Delta ADP$ and $\Delta BCP$
$$
A=\frac12 h_1 b + \frac12 h_2 b
$$
Now, we can see from the diagram that $h=h_1+h_2$, so the result follows.

Comment: Thank you Suzu, but how can we be sure that what we see from the diagram (that is, that h=h1+h2) is true? How can we be even sure that h1 and h2 lie on the same line?

Comment: @brilliant Two lines are parallel iff they form equal angles with a secant. Here $h_1,h_2$ are both perpendicular to the parallel lines $AD,BC$, so they must lie on the same line.

Comment: @dxiv - Ah! I got it. Thank you!

Comment: Thank you, Suzu. I got it now!